# Upload text file to FTP in batch file, which has random generated file name

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I have a batch file, and I want the output of it (txt) uploaded to my FTP server.

Code:

```
echo off
set /p line= Input:
echo %line%> C:\Users\Public\Folder\%random%%random%%random%%random%.txt
```

The question is;
How can I make my batch file automatically upload the generated txt which has a fully random generated name, into my FTP?

Comment: Save the randomly generated filename in another variable before you use it and then use it twice, the first time as the output file, and the second time with FTP.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Start by saving the filename in a variable, as so:

```
set FILENAME=C:\Users\Public\Folder\%RANDOM%%RANDOM%%RANDOM%.txt
```

Then, it should just be a matter of using the variable (FILENAME) in your FTP command.

Comment: How exactly do I save the file name in a variable?

Comment: Try this: 
`SET filename=C:\Users\Public\Folder\%random%%random%%random%%random%.txt`

Comment: I'm not sure how to vote for this answer because the bit about needing to store it in a variable is correct but everything else is wrong. Delayed expansion will only help here if the line is in a code block and it didn't seem to be.

Comment: Without the **delayed expansion**, this command 
`set /p line= Input:`
in the sample code provided by @Karbonis will result in:
`C:\Users\Public\Folder\%random%%random%%random%%random%.txt`

Comment: Wow, thank you so much @senpai, the code you provided (`SET filename=C:\Users\Public\Folder\%random%%random%%random%%ran‌​dom%.txt`) solved my problem, I didn't think of that!

Comment: @senpai - That's not at all how delayed expansion works, and even if it was, you'd still have to use the `!random!!random!!random!!random!` syntax to even use it.

Comment: I realized that I had misunderstood what @Karbonis was trying to achieve. I have updated my original answer.

Comment: @SomethingDark, thanks for setting me straight about delayed expansion.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the random filename to a variable, so that the `%RANDOM%` pseudo-variables are resolved only once.

And then you have to generate the `ftp` script using that variable:

```
echo off
set RANDOM_FILE=C:\Users\Public\Folder\%random%%random%%random%%random%.txt
set /p line= Input:
echo %line%> %RANDOM_FILE%

echo open hostname>ftp.txt
echo username>>ftp.txt
echo password>>ftp.txt
echo put %RANDOM_FILE%>>ftp.txt
echo bye>>ftp.txt
ftp -s:ftp.txt
```